# Dynamic Schema & Deserialization with Protostuff

Tags: serialization, deserialization, protostuff

I'm using Protostuff in an attempt to serialize/deserialize objects of several different types for which no protobuf sources are available (it's a server-server RPC scenario). Serialization goes OK because I know the type of the object to serialize and can create the schema:

```
Schema schema = RuntimeSchema.getSchema(object.getClass());
```

Now, I use `ProtobufIOUtil.toByteArray` and get a byte array which I then pass to a remote server. However, I can't seem to deserialize this byte array in the remote server because I have no way to create a schema for an object of "unknown" type. Is there any way I can get past this and use Protostuff in the same way I would use Java's native serialization?

Answer (score 1):

There are few solutions with common idea - serialize name of the class together with the data.

First one requires `protostuff-runtime`. You should create wrapper class with one field of type `Object`:

```java
public class Wrapper {
    public Object data;
}
```

Then you put your object to `data` field and serialize wrapper, `protostuff-runtime` will append class name to serialized form automatically, and later use it for deserialization.

If you want more control, then you can do similar thing without `protistuff-runtime`.

First, you need a wrapper class:

```java
public class Wrapper {
    public String clazz;
    public byte[] data;
}
```

Then you should serialize your data to byte array, store it to wrapper, and then serialize wrapper instance.

On remote side, you deserialize `Wrapper` first, then get `clazz` field - it is the class you should use to deserialize `data`.